# Meta 2 with SteamVR; Cannot move around in Unity (nearly) frozen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, htc-vive

I have a problem with the project I am working on in Unity and have been trying to solve the problem for days.

I am using the Meta 2 and the HTC Vive base station. I am continuing the work of a colleague. He was working on another computer. I am trying to recreate the project he created. He gave me the project and everything included but also doesn´t know how to solve my problem.

It looks like this: 
I can open and play the project. When I play the project I can see everything I want to see in 3D with the Meta 2. But I can not look around. When I move the Meta I see the some kind of "vibrating" movement in the screen but in the end everything stays in the position.
I also connected the Sense Gloves I have with my computer. I can move the fingers of the sense gloves in the screen (they are shown as blue circles which i can move) BUT I cannot move the whole hand. It stays where it is initialized in the room. 
I think it is a problem with the transfer of the vive tracking data to unity (the position of the tracker coordinate system in unity is not moving even though hit should).

I hope this explanation is accurate enough. If you need more information, do not hesitate to ask me, please.

Kind regards

Alex

Comment: What version of the Meta SDK are you using?  I found that the latest version was very buggy so I had to revert to the previous version.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply!

I am using the latest SDK 2.7.0.3.8. It is the only version I could find. Where could I get an older version? And which version would probably be "as new as possible" but bug free?

Kind regards

Alex

Comment: Hi, I believe 2.6 is the version I reverted back to.  With Meta not conducting business right now it might be hard to get back to that version.  Let me check on my laptop drive when I get home and if I have a copy I will send you a link to it.

Comment: Hi. 
That would be very nice, thank you!
Are you sure the problem is with the Meta, though? I can run the tutorial with the meta and move around. Also the sense gloves kinda have the same problem with the tracker.

Kind regards

Comment: No, i'm not 100 percent sure the Meta SDK is the issue but I know I could never get the 2.7 SDK to work right.

Comment: One other thought, can you try taking the HTC Vive issue out of the equation and just use the Meta hand tracking/gestures to see if you get the same behavior?

Comment: Hey. I am not at the office in the next days. I´ll come back to it next week :)

Comment: So....I got it figured out. Not sure what exactly is the problem but I think something went wrong when I imported the project. I had an activated "no movement script"....
Additionally I could fix it by choosing Component, XR, Tracked Pose driver on the Device Tracker.
I still do have the problem, that I cannot move the Controllers and the controllers are kind of bound to the view of the camera. They basically spawn and stay IN the camera….

Comment: Ok, great.  As mentioned try removing the code for the gloves and use the built-in hand tracking/gesture scripts to see if you can get that working.  If that works then add the glove code back piece by piece to see which piece of code breaks.

Comment: Well, the problem is kinda sketchy. I used vive controller instead of the gloves. I had the same problem. The next day I started the computer and suddenly I could move the controller but not the camera anymore. I now installed another Unity version, because I did not have the exact same as the developer used. I do have another problem with the meta.slammessageController. I cannot start the scene because of it....Could you maybe upload the older sdk version for the meta? I think that could actually be the problem :D

Comment: Hi yes, I will do that today.  It's on an old laptop that I will need to dust off but will get it uploaded to Google drive and send link.

Comment: Hey. Could you upload the sdk please? :)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here you go: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S2kpS0u7jGs3edDXNV7nA6YoxHYb6o2J